# JWT Laravel change password mechanism

Tags: php, laravel, api, jwt

I have implemented JWT in Laravel which is working fine so far, but I want to know that how to invalidate all tokens of a particular user when they change their password.

For Logout, I have written the following code

```
JWTAuth::invalidate();
```

Is there any way to invalidate all the token of that user?